# how to set a tab active in jQuery ui tab on page load

Tags: jquery, jquery-tabs

How can I make the final about page the default tab. I am using jQuery UI for showing these tabs.

```
<div id="tabs">
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#strains">Strains</a></li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#GB"> Browser</a></li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#pathway">Pathway</a></li>
    <li id="pathway1" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#pathway1">pathway1</a></li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#About">About</a></li>
```

As far as I have found out it seems it has to be done the following  way.

```
$('#tabs1').addClass('active')
```

But it is not working. I have following jQuery.

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
$( "#pathway1").addClass('active');
```

I want to make pathway1 page active by default.

Comment: Look at the API: http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Setting a class will not change the default tab.

Instead of

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
```

Try this:

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({ active: 4 });
```

This will make the fifth (it is zero-indexed) tab the default active tab.

Answer (score 3):

This one works for me:

```
$('a[href="#strains"]').click();
```